# Creating an Inverse Relationship after generating a value using logs and a magnitude

Tags: abstract-algebra

Apologies, the title might not be the greatest but I'll do my best to describe the problem I am having.

Currently, I have a variable `m` that represents a magnitude.

`m` can range from `.25` - `2.5`. We are treating `m=1` as the base magnitude.

Next, I have a percentage that represents a transparency value - with a max of `255`. We wanted a base transparency value equal to `100 / 255 = .392`. So, where `m = 1`, that's the transparency, `0.392`.

We also chose a maximum transparency value of `0.784`, twice the base. So, where `m = max` (right now, 2.5), the transparency is `0.784`.

Great! Now, to get the values given any magnitude between `.25` and `2.5`, I've created a function shown below:

`f(m) = 0.392 * (m^(log(2) / log(2.5)))`

Now, this is great, however my problem stems from the fact that the value that I receive needs to be, in a sense, inverted. See, when the magnitude increases, the transparency percentage (the result) should approach `0`, while the lower the magnitude, the higher the percentage should approach `.784`. The key, though, is that `m = 1` must still come out to the base of `0.392`.

This is my problem, I am not sure how to accomplish this, and I am curious if anyone has any ideas on how I can accomplish this.

Thanks in advance - this is for a senior design project for a video game that stretches shadows (hence transparency).

Comment: Your function $f$ has more open parentheses than close.

Comment: @Gaffney Fixed, and some clarifications were made by the group member writing the actual function(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want an exponential function of the form $f(m) = Ae^{-Bm}$ satisfying $f(0.25) = 0.784$ and $f(1) = 0.392$. Then solving the resulting system of equations yields $A = 0.392 \cdot 2^{4/3}$ and $B = \ln(2^{4/3})$. Note that $f(2.5) = 0.098$, which should be close enough to zero. [Wolfram|Alpha plots the following:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7C%200.392*2%5E(4%2F3)%20e%5E(-ln(2%5E(4%2F3))%20*%20m)%20%7C%20m%20%3D%200.25%20to%202.5)

[image]

---

**Edit:** Here's how to solve the system. Let $k = 0.392$. Then we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
2k = f(1/4) = Ae^{-B/4} \\
k = f(1) = Ae^{-B} 
\end{cases}
$$
Dividing the first equation by the second, we get:
$$
2 = e^{3B/4} \iff \ln 2 = \frac{3}{4}B \iff B = \frac{4}{3}\ln 2 = \ln(2^{4/3})
$$
Plugging this back into the second equation, we get:
$$
k = Ae^{-\ln(2^{4/3})} \iff A = ke^{\ln(2^{4/3})} = k \cdot 2^{4/3}
$$
as required.

Comment: This does indeed work well for the given values, at least to the extent that I'm comfortable marking this as the correct answer. What's going to be most useful for our group, though, is to know the process of how you arrived at that equation. If, for example, we decided at some future point that we wanted a different maximum than 2.5, this equation would have to change, and I'd love for us to know how to change it. In particular, we're unsure where the recurring (4/3) is springing from.

Thank you, all the same.

Comment: @PatrickMcHugh: I've edited in my derivation. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation!